# Is the a a way to bind the <BUTTON-1> event to a function when using tree view widget in python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, traceback, index-error

```py
treeView.bind('<Button-1>', select_item)
```

However, this code raises the below error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\OLWA EMMA\AppData\Lo
>       return self.func(*args)
>       File "main.py", line 118, in select
>       listOfUsers.append(str_lib['value
>       IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: The binding is fine. It appears your code is assuming that the the treeview always has a selection. You need to show us a [mcve] if you need more specific help.

Comment: Are you wanting to bind on a button click, or are you wanting to creating a binding that fires when something is selected? Those are subtly different.

Comment: I want to create a binding that fires when something is selected

Comment: Read the documentation on the `TreeView` widget, and search for `<<TreeviewSelect>>`

Comment: Thank you, let me Give it a try

Comment: Thank you so much, it has worked, my code is working fine